# Dispatch cause an undefined value when i go through my object in the reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, dispatch

I am facing a problem in my code. I am new to react-native.
I cannot go through my object in the reducer after a dispatch..

my action :

```
 export const updateConvertCurr = (listFav, id, amount) => async (dispatch) => {
try {
    const obj = {};
    _.forEach(listFav, async (value, key) => {
      const convertKey = id + '_' + value.id;
      const { data } = await axios.get('https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=' + convertKey + '&compact=ultra');
      obj[value.id] = {num: value.amount};
    });
  dispatch ({
    type: UPDATE_CURRENCY_SELECT,
    payload: obj
  });
}
catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

};

my reducer :

```
    case UPDATE_CURRENCY_SELECT:
  console.log('UPDATE_CURRENCY_SELECT');

  let newState = {...state,
         arr: state.arr.map(item => return {...item, amount: action.payload[item.id].value}),
         currSelect: {...state.currSelect}
         //currSelect: action.payload.currSelect
    };
  return {...newState};
```

action.payload[item.id].value is always undefined...

Any ideas please ?? Thank You!

Comment: Based on your `obj` in the `updateConvertCurr`  `amount` should be equivalent to `action.payload[item.id].num`